Error while making python voice speech application
I wrote a voice chat application code, but when we run this code and join a voice channel, I get the errors in the photo
error1
error2
here is my codes;
client code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import pyaudio
import socket
import threading
import time

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432


class VoiceChatApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Voice Chat Application")
        self.username = ""
        self.channel = None
        self.is_mic_on = True

        self.setup_gui()
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = None
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect_to_server()
        threading.Thread(target=self.receive_data, daemon=True).start()

    def setup_gui(self):
        self.root.geometry("300x400")
        self.root.configure(bg="#2e2e2e")

        # Title label
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Voice Chat", font=("Helvetica", 16, "bold"), fg="#ffffff", bg="#2e2e2e").pack(pady=10)

        # Username entry
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, font=("Helvetica", 12), bg="#ffffff", fg="#000000")
        self.username_entry.insert(0, "Enter username")
        self.username_entry.pack(pady=5, padx=10, fill=tk.X)

        # Set Username button
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Set Username", command=self.set_username, font=("Helvetica", 12), bg="#4CAF50",
                  fg="#ffffff", relief=tk.RAISED).pack(pady=5, padx=10, fill=tk.X)

        # Channel selection
        self.channel_var = tk.StringVar(value="Select Channel")
        self.channel_menu = tk.OptionMenu(self.root, self.channel_var, "Channel1", "Channel2")
        self.channel_menu.config(font=("Helvetica", 12), bg="#ffffff", fg="#000000")
        self.channel_menu.pack(pady=5, padx=10, fill=tk.X)

        # Join Channel button
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Join Channel", command=self.join_channel, font=("Helvetica", 12), bg="#2196F3",
                  fg="#ffffff", relief=tk.RAISED).pack(pady=5, padx=10, fill=tk.X)

        # Leave Channel button
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Leave Channel", command=self.leave_channel, font=("Helvetica", 12), bg="#FFC107",
                  fg="#ffffff", relief=tk.RAISED).pack(pady=5, padx=10, fill=tk.X)

        # Current Channel label
        self.current_channel_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Current Channel: None", font=("Helvetica", 12),
                                              fg="#ffffff", bg="#2e2e2e")
        self.current_channel_label.pack(pady=5)

        # Mute button
        self.mute_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Mute Microphone", command=self.toggle_mic, font=("Helvetica", 12),
                                     bg="#F44336", fg="#ffffff", relief=tk.RAISED)
        self.mute_button.pack(pady=5, padx=10, fill=tk.X)

        # User list
        self.user_list_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Users in Channel:", font=("Helvetica", 12), fg="#ffffff",
                                        bg="#2e2e2e")
        self.user_list_label.pack(pady=5)
        self.user_listbox = tk.Listbox(self.root, font=("Helvetica", 12), bg="#ffffff", fg="#000000")
        self.user_listbox.pack(pady=5, padx=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Exit button
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit Application", command=self.exit_application, font=("Helvetica", 12),
                  bg="#F44336", fg="#ffffff", relief=tk.RAISED).pack(pady=5, padx=10, fill=tk.X)

    def connect_to_server(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Connection attempt failed: {e}")
                time.sleep(5)

    def set_username(self):
        self.username = self.username_entry.get()
        if not self.username:
            messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Username cannot be empty")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Info", f"Username set to {self.username}")

    def join_channel(self):
        self.channel = self.channel_var.get()
        if self.channel in ["Channel1", "Channel2"]:
            message = f"JOIN|{self.channel}|{self.username}"
            try:
                self.socket.send(message.encode())
                self.start_audio_stream()
                self.current_channel_label.config(text=f"Current Channel: {self.channel}")
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Connection Error", f"Unable to send message to server: {e}")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please select a valid channel")

    def leave_channel(self):
        if self.channel:
            message = f"LEAVE|{self.channel}|{self.username}"
            try:
                self.socket.send(message.encode())
                self.stop_audio_stream()
                self.current_channel_label.config(text="Current Channel: None")
                self.channel = None
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Connection Error", f"Unable to send message to server: {e}")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "You are not in a channel")

    def start_audio_stream(self):
        try:
            device_index = None
            for i in range(self.p.get_device_count()):
                info = self.p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
                if info['maxInputChannels'] > 0:
                    device_index = i
                    break

            if device_index is None:
                raise ValueError("No input device found")

            self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                      channels=1,
                                      rate=44100,
                                      input=True,
                                      input_device_index=device_index,
                                      frames_per_buffer=1024,
                                      stream_callback=self.audio_callback)
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Audio Error", f"Unable to start audio stream: {e}")

    def audio_callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        if self.is_mic_on:
            try:
                self.socket.sendall(in_data)
            except (BrokenPipeError, ConnectionResetError, ConnectionAbortedError) as e:
                print(f"Audio send error: {e}")
                self.stop_audio_stream()

                messagebox.showerror("Connection Error", "Connection lost while sending audio data")
        return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)

    def stop_audio_stream(self):
        if self.stream:
            try:
                self.stream.stop_stream()
                self.stream.close()
            except IOError as e:
                print(f"Stream stop error: {e}")
            self.stream = None

    def toggle_mic(self):
        self.is_mic_on = not self.is_mic_on
        status = "Muted" if not self.is_mic_on else "Unmuted"
        self.mute_button.config(text=f"Microphone {status}")

    def receive_data(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = self.socket.recv(1024).decode()
                if message.startswith("UPDATE"):
                    _, channel, users = message.split('|', 2)
                    self.user_listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
                    for user in users.split(', '):
                        self.user_listbox.insert(tk.END, user)
            except (ConnectionResetError, ConnectionAbortedError) as e:
                print(f"Receive data error: {e}")
                self.connect_to_server()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")

    def exit_application(self):
        if self.stream:
            self.stop_audio_stream()
        self.socket.close()
        self.root.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = VoiceChatApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

server code:
import socket
import threading


HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432


channels = {"Channel1": [], "Channel2": []}
connections = []

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"Yeni bağlantı: {addr}")
    try:
        while True:
            message = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            if not message:
                break
            command = message.split('|')
            if command[0] == "JOIN":
                channel = command[1]
                username = command[2]
                if channel in channels:
                    channels[channel].append(username)
                    update_users_in_channel(channel)
            elif command[0] == "LEAVE":
                channel = command[1]
                username = command[2]
                if channel in channels and username in channels[channel]:
                    channels[channel].remove(username)
                    update_users_in_channel(channel)

    except (ConnectionResetError, ConnectionAbortedError) as e:
        print(f"Connection error: {e}")
    finally:
        conn.close()
        connections.remove(conn)
        print(f"Bağlantı kapandı: {addr}")

def update_users_in_channel(channel):
    user_list = ', '.join(channels[channel])
    message = f"UPDATE|{channel}|{user_list}"
    for conn in connections:
        try:
            conn.send(message.encode())
        except (BrokenPipeError, ConnectionResetError) as e:
            print(f"Broadcast error: {e}")
            connections.remove(conn)

def start_server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen()
    print("Sunucu başlatıldı ve dinleniyor...")

    while True:
        conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
        connections.append(conn)
        threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr), daemon=True).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()

I can't understand what's wrong
I would be very grateful if you could help me.
I'm trying to improve myself by making a discord replica with a simple interface. i also got help from chatgpt while writing the code. but he couldn't find a solution to this error i got.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The community is here to help. However, your code is a bit long, so please provide a minimal reproducible example if possible.

i dont know how can i do @LukeL

At this point I can't yet find the relevant part of your code. But obviously some of it doesn't matter to the issue you're currently solving. That's why I directed you to see the link. Did you read it already?
